# Nested numbered list with decimal formatting

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a bulleted list that has a numbered sublist that I can't get to format as I want.

```
- foo
- bar
   1. some
   1. thing
   1. else
- baz
```

On GitHub this renders as:

```
 - foo
 - bar
     i. some
    ii. thing
   iii. else
 - baz
```

What I'd like is:

```
 - foo
 - bar
     1. some
     2. thing
     3. else
 - baz
```

The following issue didn't seem to help https://github.com/github/markup/issues/210

This is not a duplicate of [Markdown: What's the proper way to do a continued list inside of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101316) as that is about how to have the numbering continue across higher level list elements.

Comment: Seems you can't. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101316/markdown-whats-the-proper-way-to-do-a-continued-list-inside-of-a-list/.

Comment: That question looks to be about getting the numbers to continue across higher level list items. I just want it to use the first level numbered list for the numbered list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a Markdown issue; Markdown cares about semantics, not presentation. This is about how the generated `<ol>` is styled.

GitHub doesn't permit custom styling¹ of their rendered Markup, and that includes setting `list-style-type` to `decimal`. You're stuck with the styles they've chosen.

---

¹E.g., see [How to add color to Github's README.md file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509830/354577), [Which inline html styles does GitHub markdown accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44831505/354577), and [How to retain HTML formatting in GitHub readme file upon upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50786752/354577).